# Как зациклить данное преобразование?(Алгоритм поворота многоугольника)

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

В общем имеются координаты вершин фигуры.

При пропорциональном увеличении фигуры координаты вершин изменяются по формулам которая на скрине. На скрине пример для треугольника. Нужно как-то это зациклить, чтобы можно было увеличивать и многоугольники со скольким угодно количеством вершин. Есть идеи?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в конечном итоге? Для меня не понятны термин "зациклить" в контексте данного вопроса, и что значит вращать?

Comment: Описался. Не вращать, а увеличивать. В конечном итоге хочу получить координаты вершин увеличенного треугольника, и эти координаты вычисляются по тем формулам что на фото. Но как сделать цикл? Допустим, я захочу увеличить многоугольник, соответственно нужен цикл который все это преобразование координат совершать

Comment: Цикл используется для повторения одного и того же действия N раз. Пока я не вижу где тут применять циклы, приведите пример формулы для N-угольника

Comment: xA'= [2λ+1)xA-(λ-1)(xB+xC)]/3;
xB'= [2λ+1)xB-(λ-1)(xA+xC)]/3;
xC'= [2λ+1)xC-(λ-1)(xA+xB)]/3; - это получается для фигуры с тремя вершинами. Соответсвенно, если фигура с 4-мя вершинами, то получается  

xA'= [2λ+1)xA-(λ-1)(xB+xC+xD)]/3;

xB'= [2λ+1)xB-(λ-1)(xA+xC+xD)]/3;

xC'= [2λ+1)xC-(λ-1)(xA+xB+xD)]/3;

xD’ = [2λ+1)xD-(λ-1)(xA+xB+xC)]

 Вроде бы так? А вот если многоугольник с 10 вершинами - нужен же какой то цикл?

Comment: Ну так не делайте переменные `xA`, `xB` и так далее, сделайте массив...

Comment: Так у меня и так массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно эти формулы применять для многоугольника, будет много повторных ненужных действий.

Вычислите координаты CX, CY центра как сумму координат вершин, делённую на количество вершин (отдельно для X и Y)

Потом используйте эти координаты для преобразования каждой вершины

```
for i = 0.. NumVerttices - 1:
  X[i] = CX + (initial_X[i] - CX) * coeff
  Y[i] = CY + (initial_Y[i] - CY) * coeff
```

где coeff - масштабный коэффициент  (>1 для увеличения )

Comment: А разве при данном преобразовании центр не сместится? Да, забыл указать - условие: преобразование должно быть такое, чтобы центр треугольника сохранялся при любом увеличении.

Comment: Нет, конечно. Для этого такие формулы и придуманы

Comment: Ах, все, понятно. Спасибо. Действительно любой многоугольник можно увеличивать